# PHPUnit configuration option to list executed tests

Tags: php, configuration, phpunit, command-line-interface

How to get a list of all test classes and methods in order they ware executed by PHPUnit printed to stdout? Is there any configuration option that turns on such information?

I'm using PHPUnit 7.5.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: try activating the `verbose` flag adding the  `--verbose` as command line argument

Comment: also `--debug` could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `debug` flag as described in the doc in the [command-line test runner](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.5/textui.html):

> ```
> --verbose
> ```
>
> Output more verbose information, for instance the names of tests that
>   were incomplete or have been skipped.
>
> ```
> --debug
> ```
>
> Output debug information such as the name of a test when its execution
>   starts.

Hope this help

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use the switch:

```
--testdox
```

It provides a nice grouped list of test results that are quick and easy to read